# Cut and pasting large files to Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

Dropbox advises that users drag and drop from their Windows Explorer to the Dropbox directory. Looking at the desktop icons, it appears drag and drop in this case does not remove the original.

Trying cut and paste for some large files, I see that the blue synch icon does not seem to go away after several hours and that suggests that it is a failed operation without any explicit indication of failure. Since the files are large, it's not clear yet if it eventually succeeds.

Trying cut and paste for a small file, it succeeds, even though the "cut" aspect of cut and paste would seem to render any synch operation impossible.

Is cut and paste a certain failure without any sort of error message or warning when it comes to large files?

Comment: There isn't a functional difference between those actions.  In both cases if an existing file exists you will get a prompt to replace the file or create a copy of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was observed that the upload to the cloud eventually succeeds, that is the, synch icon changes to the check mark icon. The fact that there may be no corresponding file on the computer that was the source, due to it having been cut, does not seem to cause a failure.